# Asp.net web page visible in xml format in view page source but looks user friendly on browser?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

Please look at this sample link address: (weather.gov)

http://140.90.113.200/xml/current_obs/KLAX.xml

if you view page source in browser, you can see that  it shows data in XML format (usng xsl.?).

I need to implement a simple web page like that.

I think that web site uses XML XSL ...

I'm going to implement a web application in asp.net which will use data stored in sql database (or xml database or web service) and show these information like other normal web sites but in xml format in nice UI (using xsl?).That Weather website is only a sample to show what i want to do (i will not use any data from that site, my application is different).My requirement is **being able to *view page source* only in XML format**.Now I'm clear that xsl is the solution for that, but considering to use this method in asp.net.(use xml/xsl in dynamic asp.net pages)

My Question?

It is important for me to make the web page output in xml format(visible in xml format in page view source) but looks user friendly for users.

1.how can i do it in asp.net ?

Please guide me. I appreciate any sample application,url, code or information to make it clear.

Thanks.

Comment: @csharper2020: If you are well versed in ASP.Net, then you know the basics of population pattern. An XSLT example here in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529852/sitemesh-like-functionality-with-xslt/3533226

Comment: @drachenstern- No, not yet,.. I have problem regarding dynamic generating of xml..(I think its related to header of xml page which returns from xmldatadocument? I don know why the page source in browser is not xml structured)...

Comment: The webpage you referenced is just an XML file with an XSLT reference. You need to read up on XML and XSLT and understand that XSLT is markup to tell the XML how to prepare itself. Then you can use the website to generate XML based on routing to provide a easy to use website.

Comment: @drachenstern As a simple test(in ASP.NET,SQL),I've used a Dataset to store data which come from DB,then fill out XmlDataDocument. Then XslCompiledTransform and XmlTextWriter used to load defined xsl.. Finally styled xml page will send to page using Response.OutputStream. After running page, it seems xml page styled using xsl but my main problem still remains: The Page is not structured in XML format when I view Page Source in browser..

Comment: I believe it's time for you to share some code, so we can replicate.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/279446#279446

Answer (score 3):

view-source:http://140.90.113.200/latest_ob.xsl

That should help you get an idea what you need to do, no?

Comment: Thank you drachenstern. Do you know what is the name of this method of presenting data in asp.net? Actually I want to use asp.net and sql database.

Comment: I dont think asp.net is involved in this case. You are taking an xml file and an xsl file and using xslt to combine the both. By adding the xslt stylesheet to the top of the xml document it automatically kicks in combines the two when viewed in a web browser. If you wanted to output xml and then have the option of displaying it you should look into writing a wcf service to serve up the xml.

Comment: @rtpHarry ~ Exactly what I was going to suggest. @csharper2020 I believe you would just call it using an XSL transform on XML data... I can see you are not familiar with either XML or XSL are you? I suggest you to read some posts here on stackoverflow for XSL and XML.

Comment: Thanks dear friends..  rtpHarry you're right i do not have experiment on xsl. But however I want to implement my simple website by asp.net, so asked how to do this part also in asp.net. my main problem is accessing to web page data in page source in xml format. It seems the only way is using xml xslt? In http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/display.php?stid=KLAX  that website uses  query string to show relative data.

Comment: @csharper2020: Full XML/XSLT driven site example: http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar . In fact, this use PHP/MySQL as backend for producing XML response.

Comment: @csharper2020 - I think I might be misunderstanding you. Is your actual requirement to build an asp.net website and then pull the xml weather feed data in to it? If this is the case youre talking about a completely different set of technologies and you should update your question at the top so developers can answer you.

Comment: @rtpHarry ~ I agree, I'm not entirely sure what he's asking, but I realize there is a language barrier.

Comment: @rtpHarry - I'm going to implement a web application in asp.net which will use data stored in sql database (or xml database or web service) and show these information like other normal web sites but in xml format in nice UI (using xsl?).That Weather website is only a sample to show what i want to do (i will not use any data from that site, my application is different).My requirement is being able to view page source only in XML format.Now I'm clear that xsl is the solution for that, but considering to use this method in asp.net.(use xml/xsl in dynamic asp.net pages).

Comment: I would use asp.net to design the XSL transform stylesheet, and do the layout work and such and whatnot, and then I would have the actual XML being served by a WCF (or ASMX?) framework with perhaps a REST architecture.

Answer (score 1):

ok,..
As a simple test(in ASP.NET,SQL),I've used a Dataset to store data which come from DB,then fill out XmlDataDocument. Then XslCompiledTransform and XmlTextWriter used to load defined xsl.. Finally styled xml page will send to page using Response.OutputStream. After running page, it seems xml page styled using xsl but **my main problem still remains**:
Simple Database is a SQL database with a table which contains 4 columns :ID,Name,Age,Phone
**THIS IS My Default.aspx.cs** (Code) - (I didn't change predefined design of default.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        Conn.Open();

        DataSet DS = new DataSet("TestDataSet");

        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableTest", Conn);
        DA.Fill(DS, "Persons");

        Conn.Close();

        DS.EnforceConstraints = false;
        XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(DS);

        // Create a procesing instruction.  
        XmlProcessingInstruction newPI;

        String PItext = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>'";
        newPI = xmlDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", PItext);

        // Add the processing instruction node to the document.  
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(newPI);


        XslCompiledTransform xslTran = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslTran.Load(MapPath("TestTransform.xsl"));
       // Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer);
        writer.Close();

    }
}
```

And This is simple XSL file (TestTransform.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="Persons">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
         Simple Test : Information for : <xsl:value-of select="Name/text()"/>
        </title>

      </head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .label { font-weight: bold; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: right;}
        .xsllocation { font-size: 18px; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
      </style>
      <body bgcolor="#ddffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" background="/images/background1.gif">

        <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0">


          <td width="525" valign="top">
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tr valign="top">
                <td>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</td>
                <td width="100%" align="center">
                  <a name="contents" id="contents"></a>
                  <table style="margin-left: 10px;" align="left">



                    <xsl:variable name="name">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Name/text()"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="$name != 'NA' and $name != ''">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="label">Name is:</td>
                        <td>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$name"/>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:if>


                    <xsl:variable name="age">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Age/text()"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="$age != 'NA' and $age != ''">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="label">Age:</td>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:copy-of select="$age"/> years old
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:variable name="phone">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Phone/text()"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="$phone != 'NA' and $phone != ''">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="label">Phone Number:</td>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:copy-of select="$phone"/> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1.below is **Result of that simple code page When I run it** and view in **page source** (using browser) It shows html tags (like body,td,...):

```
<html xmlns:str="http://xsltsl.org/string"><head><title>
         Simple Test : Information for : Mr Abc              </title></head><style type="text/css">
        .label { font-weight: bold; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: right;}
        .xsllocation { font-size: 18px; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
      </style><body bgcolor="#ddffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" background="/images/background1.gif"><table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0"><td width="525" valign="top"><table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr valign="top"><td>       </td><td width="100%" align="center"><a name="contents" id="contents" /><table style="margin-left: 10px;" align="left"><tr><td class="label">Name is:</td><td>Mr Abc              </td></tr><tr><td class="label">Age:</td><td>32 years old
                        </td></tr><tr><td class="label">Phone Number:</td><td>345353232 </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></table></body></html>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZKwzWK/GivBcwTW8PWk8wUf8dacg" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but as I said before I need to make it looks like that mentioned weather page (please view page source in browser).. **Something like this:** **when** i click on page view source on browser...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="TestTransform.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Persons version="1.0"  
    <Name>Mr Abc</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Phone>345353232</Phone>    
</Persons>
```

Whats the problem??
How can i do (solve) that in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You need a tutorial on XML transformation using XSLT:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp