# Apply XSL template in external XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

The webpages I am working on display a main page area whose content comes from an external xml file which contains the required HTML.

e.g.

```
<xhtml:content>
    <div id="marketingContent">
      <div id="topLeft">
        <div id="intro"> .....
```

We have an XSL template that consumes this xml and displays it in the full page.

This is currently static content, however there is a requirement to display a number of links within this content dynamically based upon what page you are.

We have this info in another xml file but would like to inject a xsl template to display these links within the external xml file.

e.g.

```
 <xhtml:content>
        <div id="marketingContent">
          <div id="topLeft">
            <div id="intro">
                <!-- Dynamic link area -->
                <div id="links">
                  list of links based on the area of the site you are in
                </div> ....
```

Is this possible to do, and what is the best method - fairly new to xsl

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seeing your XSLT would help, really.

Comment: @user502014: This looks like a population pattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529852/sitemesh-like-functionality-with-xslt

Comment: This isn't an XSLT question at all. What is needed is: 1. A complete (but smallest possible) source XML document. 2.The wanted result. 3. A set of rules/requirements how the items in the result are related to the items in the XML document. Withouth these we can only guess what actually is your problem. Please, supply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [document()-function](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp) from within your XSLT-file which displays the main page, to load another XML-document (say into a variable). Using xpath, you can then select your required nodes from this document.

An article explaining what you can do with this can be found [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/06/xslt.html).

I'd love to go more in-depth but you'll have to post a bit more, or we're limited to being slightly vague and general in our answers to your question.