# Alternative approach to HTML generation

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

My program generates HTML via stringbuilder.

```
         sbHTMLHeader.Append("<div id=\"printableContent\">");
         sbHTMLHeader.Append("<div id=\"packingSlipHeader\">");
         sbHTMLHeader.Append("<div class=\"floatLeft\"><img src=\"../images/logo.gif\" alt=\"Logo\" /></div>");
//...
if (!orderType.Equals("L"))
            {
                sbHTMLHeader.Append("     <td>" + orderData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["carrier"] + "</td>" + Environment.NewLine);
                //...
            }
            else
            {
                sbHTMLHeader.Append("     <td></td>" + Environment.NewLine);
                 //...
            }
//...
```

380 lines later, I am passionitely against this code.  In the past, I used [Altova Stylevision.](http://www.altova.com/stylevision/xslt-html.html)  At my current job we have no license for the product. I don't need any of the PDF or other templates it provides, just HTML.  Can you suggest a powerful, readable alternative to generate HTML such as above?

Comment: You can use a population pattern in XSLT like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3529852/357812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to store all the data in an XML file and write an XSLT (transformation sheet) that turns it into HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As usually I can recommend: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

In another approach you can use classes from [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tct4wcsd.aspx) namespace to create html.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use [NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html) to help out with generating such templated HTML. The [basic syntax](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/usingit.html) is easy, and you can go quite complicated. Should save you a lot of tedious coding, and it doesn't require that you massage your input data beforehand.