# Formatting a string with XML and XSLT like sptrinf() in PHP

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I am coding a website that has the the language string separated in a xml files. Depending on the language, I include one or another. There is no problem with that.

By the way, this site is a dynamic so will have for example a string like *Hello ipalaus!* in English, like *Bienvenido ipalaus!*, etcetera. In this case we have the same order of words but in some case probably will be *name string*, *string name*, *string name string*...

There is anyway to reply what `sprintf()` does in PHP? In PHP we have this:

```
<?php
$name = "ipalaus";
$string = "Welcome %s";

echo sprintf($string, $name);

// OUTPUTS: Welcome ipalaus
?>
```

I would like to have in my **index.en.xml** some like:

```
<language>
    <welcome>Welcome %s</welcome>
</language>
```

In my **index.xml**, the one generated with PHP, will have:

```
<index>
    <locale>en</locale>

    <welcome>ipalaus</welcome>
</index>
```

And, in the XSLT file, represent **Welcome ipalaus**.

Actually, in my XSLT file, I use this to load the language:

```
<xsl:param name="language" select="document(concat('../lang/', $locale, '/index.xml'))" />
```

Accessing to the values with: `<xsl:value-of select="$base/language/welcome" />`.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** A example for a question to Alejandro about his totally valid response:

```
<index>
    <video>
        <author>ipalaus</author>
    </video>
    <video>
        <author>Alejandro</author>
    </video>
</index>
```

And a language file:

```
<language>
    <video>
        <made>This videos is made by <author/></made>
        <random>Another string</random>
    </video>
</language>
```

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986408/how-to-fill-text-templates-using-xslt

Comment: I dont understand it at all. It posted a example, but I'm looking a way to parse it as a large scale, so I don't have to repeat for each variable because can be extremely hard on a large scale project. Note that have to mixes with to different XML files. There is anyway?

Comment: @Alejandro, don't you see anything I can do? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example, this `index.xml`:

```
<index> 
    <locale>en</locale> 
    <name>ipalaus</name> 
</index>
```

And this `index.en.xml`:

```
<language>
    <welcome>Welcome <name/></welcome>
</language>
```

Then, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pLayoutURI" select="'index.en.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vData" select="/index"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLayout" select="document($pLayoutURI,/)/language"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <h1><xsl:apply-templates select="$vLayout/welcome"/></h1>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="language/*/*[not(node())]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vData/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <h1>Welcome ipalaus</h1>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pLayoutURI" select="'index.en.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLayout" select="document($pLayoutURI,/)/language"/>
    <xsl:template match="/index">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="video">
        <li>
            <video src="{url}">
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLayout/video/made/node()"
                                         mode="populate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pContext" select="."/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </video>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="language//*[not(node())]" mode="populate">
        <xsl:param name="pContext" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pContext/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<index>
    <video>
        <author>ipalaus</author>
        <url>ipalaus.mpg</url>
    </video>
    <video>
        <author>Alejandro</author>
        <url>Alejandro.mpg</url>
    </video>
</index>
```

And this external source `index.en.xml`:

```
<language>
    <video>
        <made>This videos is made by <author/></made>
        <random>Another string</random>
    </video>
</language>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <video src="ipalaus.mpg" title="This videos is made by ipalaus"/>
   </li>
   <li>
      <video src="Alejandro.mpg" title="This videos is made by Alejandro"/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Alejandro! To be a little more complicated, will be some way to use in index something like the **EDIT** in the answer? To access to a child? Sorry for my complication, and thank you another time for your useful help and time!