# String.Format("Your query {0} with {1} Placeholders", theQuery, results.Count) Equivalent in XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt

Is there an equivalent function to string format in XSLT?

I'm working on a multi-lingual site in umbraco. I'm not aware of what languages will be needed, butbeing as they are, one language could order the words differently e.g.

English "Your query 'Duncan' matched 5 results." could translate word for word to 
"5 results matched 'Duncan' query".

For this reason having a item for "Your query", "matched" and "results" in my umbraco translation isn't feasible. If I was to make this a user control for C# I would have the translator to provide a dictionary item like "Your query '{0}' matched {1} results".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a string with XML and XSLT like sptrinf() in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078447/formatting-a-string-with-xml-and-xslt-like-sptrinf-in-php)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and pure XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an equivalent function to
>   string format in XSLT?

**This is a close analog in XSLT**:

The dictionary entry has the following format:

```
<t>Your query "<query/>" matched <nResults/> results</t>
```

**The transformation (corresponding to `string.format()`) is very simple:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="pQuery" select="'XPath and XSLT'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNumResults" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="query">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pQuery"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="nResults">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pNumResults"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and it produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Your query "XPath and XSLT" matched 3 results
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your XSLT with a custom function:
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/extend-your-xslt-with-custom-functions.

Comment: Could you please comment, why this answer is not useful!

Comment: The question was umbraco specific, so +1.