# Transform XML into HTML using XSLT

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, asp.net-3.5

I saw several questions related to XML, XSLT and HTML on stackoverflow, but I beleive my question is a little different. Here is what I need:

I need to send an email to my customers. The wordings of the email can differ based upon the scenario. Each scenario has a corresponding format saved in the database. For example, one scenario might require this email:

*Scenario 1: We have opened Ticket XXX/Reference Number XXX for your call on XXX. Kindly call us at XXX to track progress.*

Another scenario might required this email:

*Scenario 2: Thanks for your interest in our Product XXX. As discussed we will send our representative on XXX to your office located at XXX.*

Also, the format might need to be altered a bit depending upon data availability. e.g. if I need to send email corresponding to scenario 1, and I don't have Reference Number available, I want to remove the reference number part completely on the fly (not in database) i.e. I want something like this:

*Scenario 3: We have opened Ticket XXX for your call on XXX. Kindly call us at XXX to track progress.*

The formats for scenarios 1 and 2 are stored in the database as XSLT corresponding to the strings you see above. Format for Scenario 3 has to be produced on the fly. The XXX part has to be replaced with actual data. This data is available in an XML serializable object that I have.

I want to serialize this object, produce an XML in memory, modify the XSLT a little (on the fly) to reflect the data I have, transform the XML in memory to HTML using the XSLT for the scenario and then pass the HTML as a string parameter to an email method I have. The email part works. I need to work on the Object->XML in memory->Slight XSLT modification-> HTML using appropriate XSLT.

I would appreciate if you can include code examples and not just the approach I need to follow.

EDIT:

Here is the working code:

```
using (xsltStream = new MemoryStream(emailInfo.Body))
            {
                // Create an XmlReader from the Stream
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xsltStream);

                // Create and load the transform with document function enabled.
                XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
                settings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
                transform.Load(reader, settings, null);

                // Execute the transformation.
                transform.Transform(doc, writer);
             }
```

Comment: XSLT supports parameters, which can be passed from the client code.  You might be able to avoid the "on-the-fly" modifications you mentioned (which sounds like a hack).

Comment: Why not to just have 3 XSLT files? No need to any modifications for XSLT...

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to fill text templates using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986408/how-to-fill-text-templates-using-xslt). The only new requeriment is to use multiple layouts: choose the layout based on some assertion before transverse it.

Comment: Thanks @harpo. I am aware of parameters that can fill data values. However, what I need to do here is change the template itself and not just the data values. I would be grateful if you can share a code sample if this can be achieved through parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Alexei. I am not entirely averse to having different templates. However, I was avoiding that because in my actual application, the emails wouldn't be one liners. They are much bigger and have lots of data that might not be available to me when I send an email. If I were to have a template for each permutation-combination, I might end up with 10-20 templates for essentially 3 kinds of emails that I need to send.

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro. I found the link quite helpful. However, it doesn't have C# code. I was able to successfully use XslTransform class with your technique and it works. But, I am unable to get it working with the recommended XslCompiledTransform class. I would be highly grateful if you could post some code that leverages XslCompiledTransform class alonwith XMLReader/Writer, etc... whatever is needed to produce, read and use the XML from my object. Also, I believe, I would need to enable scripting and documents explicity in code.

Comment: @Yasir: There are a lot of experts' answers about `C#` and `XslCompiledTransform`. Do a search like http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%23+XslCompiledTransform

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro. I was able to figure the XslCompliledTransform part after several searches, trials and errors. Now, I just need to figure out the template modification part in case I don't have all the data for a template.

Comment: @Yasir - if you put all data you need in the XML you will need just 3 templates (or as many as different results you need). If you can't add data to XML - adding parameters to XSLT transform is better than changing XSLT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon comments from @harpo, @Alexei Levenkov and @Alejandro, I was able to work out a working version of the code which uses multiple templates. Since I can't mark the comments as answers, I will mark this as answer and add the code in my question.

```
using (xsltStream = new MemoryStream(emailInfo.Body))
            {
                // Create an XmlReader from the Stream
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xsltStream);

                // Create and load the transform with document function enabled.
                XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
                settings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
                transform.Load(reader, settings, null);

                // Execute the transformation.
                transform.Transform(doc, writer);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The formats for scenarios 1 and 2 are stored in the database as XSLT

I think I would be quite inclined to store the formats as XML rather than as XSLT:

```
<message>Thanks for your interest in our Product <product/>. As discussed we will send our representative on <date/> to your office located at <officeLocation/>.</message>
```

Then you use a standard stylesheet to transform this document, using data from another document.

Having said this, I only recommend this because I did it myself the way you are describing and regret it, as it's too difficult to make changes or introduce new variations.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Can you illustrate the approach using some code.