# xsl translation system

Tags: php, xslt, translation

I am using PHP as a programming language and for presentational logic (for my output) I am using XSL.

Now I need to create translation system for my project. What is the best way to do translations in xslt?

from the Google search I see that there are two options:

1. **Register Functions in PHP XSL**, but i do not like this idea, because i whant to keep my presentation logic as separate as possible
2. **Load xml file with translations into xsl variable**, but what if there are variables in translation string?

Maybe there are some other options how to translate text? What is the best way?

Thank you

Comment: @Tomas: Typically you would have a catalog of XML resources with the different translations. I don't understand the requirement of _"there are variables in translation string"_?

Comment: lets say I need to translate `"enter number between 1 and 10"` where `1` and `10` are variables and can change. In my code this line now looks something like this `"enter number between <xsl:copy-of select="view/startnumber"/> and <xsl:copy-of select="view/endnumber"/>"`. If I load translations from XML dictionary how I have to deal with that parts that may change?

Comment: @Tomas: For that you should be using a population pattern like the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986408/how-to-fill-text-templates-using-xslt

Comment: @Alejandro: i looked at article you given above and it works fine, but is it possible something like this: xml `<trs><tr lang="en" id="str1">enter number between $sn and $en</tr><tr lang="lt" id="str1">iveskite skaiciu tarp $sn ir $en</tr></trs>` and in xsl template I output `str1` by needed language, but how to set `$sn` and `$en`. Everything is in translate file (there are no hardcoded text in xsl template)

Comment: @Tomas: You should use elements for value replacement instead.

Comment: @Alejandro: If I use elements I get nothing. Xml `<tr lang="en" id="str1">enter number between <sn/> and </en></tr>` xsl: `<xsl:value-of select="str1"/>`. I just get `enter number between and`. How can I catch and replace these elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 exclude-result-prefixes="html">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="translation html:*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kResourceById" match="resource" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vConfig" select="/config"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vCatalog" select="document('catalog.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('layout.xml')/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="html:*[@id]">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vCatalog">
                <xsl:variable name="vResource"
                 select="key('kResourceById',$vCurrent/@id)"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="($vResource/translation[@xml:lang=$vConfig/lang]
                          |$vCurrent[not($vResource)])/node()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::html:*)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates
         select="$vConfig/*[name()=name(current())]/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<config>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <sn>1</sn>
    <en>10</en>
</config>
```

And `catalog.xml`:

```
<catalog>
    <resource id="str1">
        <translation xml:lang="en"
                    >enter number between <sn/> and <en/>.</translation>
        <translation xml:lang="lt"
                    >iveskite skaiciu tarp <sn/> ir <en/>.</translation>
    </resource>
</catalog>
```

And `layout.xml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <form>
            <label id="str1"/>
            <input id="val1" type="input"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <form>
            <label id="str1">enter number between 1 and 10.</label>
            <input id="val1" type="input"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this input:

```
<config>
    <lang>lt</lang>
    <sn>20</sn>
    <en>30</en>
</config>
```

Output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <form>
            <label id="str1">iveskite skaiciu tarp 20 ir 30.</label>
            <input id="val1" type="input"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```